Grad-Cam with InceptionV3 keras
I wanted to display a heatmap overlaying my images using grad-cam (or another method that you find suitable).
This is the architecture of the model (base_model is InceptionV3)
        model = Sequential([ base_model, Flatten(), Dense(128, activation='relu'), Dropout(dropout1), Dense(64, activation='relu'), Dropout(dropout2), Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ])
I am having trouble finding a way to do it. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? A tutorial or something?
Thank you very much.
